# Custom Post Type menu name

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type with my requirements. I used "WP Video Gen" as menu label. But I want red marked item to name as "Videos". Is it possible?
Ref: http://ScrnSht.com/jcvlhy

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you register your custom post type there's an argument called 'labels' you can pass to `register_post_type()`. The argument is an associative array with named labels for the menu and screens of your post type. Specifically, the label you are looking for is called 'all_items'.

I don't know your code for registering the post type, but here's a short example that does what you asked for:

```
function video_gen_init() {
    register_post_type( 'video_gen', array(
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name'      => 'WP Video Gen',
            'all_items' => 'Videos',
        ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'video_gen_init' );
```

Other available labels are (according to the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) by the time of writing):

- 'name' - general name for the post type, usually plural. The same as, and overridden by $post_type_object->label
- 'singular_name' - name for one object of this post type. Defaults to value of name
- 'add_new' - the add new text. The default is Add New for both
  hierarchical and non-hierarchical types. When internationalizing this
  string, please use a gettext context matching your post type.
  Example: _x('Add New', 'product');
- 'all_items' - the all items text used in the menu. Default is the
  Name label
- 'add_new_item' - the add new item text. Default is Add New Post/Add
  New Page
- 'edit_item' - the edit item text. Default is Edit Post/Edit Page
- 'new_item' - the new item text. Default is New Post/New Page
- 'view_item' - the view item text. Default is View Post/View Page
- 'search_items' - the search items text. Default is Search
  Posts/Search Pages
- 'not_found' - the not found text. Default is No posts found/No pages
  found
- 'not_found_in_trash' - the not found in trash text. Default is No
  posts found in Trash/No pages found in Trash
- 'parent_item_colon' - the parent text. This string isn't used on
  non-hierarchical types. In hierarchical ones the default is Parent
  Page
- 'menu_name' - the menu name text. This string is the name to give
  menu items. Defaults to value of name

Comment: `'all_items' => 'Videos',` worked like charm. Thank you for your answer.
Yes, the previous answer was wrong, Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> Is it possible?

**Sorry, but no**, this is not possible, due to the internal logic that WordPress applies to rendering the menu. The first submenu item is always the same as the Top level menu item (until you don't apply a fix that avoids copying them at all - not recommended as it destroys the default behavior and messes with what the user expects and sees with the remaining menu items).

#### Details

You can read more about [changing how menu items behave in my article here](http://unserkaiser.com/code/wordpress-admin-menu-in-detail/).

Comment: Sorry but your answer was not correct, @alisspers just explained. Anyway, thanks for your time.